# Are those statements about solvable systems correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have some questions  about solvable systems.
First of all: I'm not a student I just try to understand how this work, so this won't be 100% mathematical correct sorry.

Given is a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbf{b} \neq \mathbf{0}$. 
´
Which statements apply to the choice of $A$ and $b$, for which $Ax = b$ has exactly one solution? (original Question of a textbook)

1. $\mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$
2. $\|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\|=\left\|\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{A}^{\top} \mathbf{A}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{\top} \mathbf{b}\right\|$
3. $\|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\|=\left\|\mathbf{A}^{\top} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\right\|$

I want to start with 3. because this is maybe the easy question.

So be $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $m = 3$ and $n=2$. Than $Ax$ will be an $2 \times 2$ matrix and $A^TAx$ will be an $1 \times 1$ vector. So the equation of thos two norms can not be correct.

Now to statement 1.:

We know that $b \neq 0$ so $Ax=0$ should be wrong, or am I missing something?

Statement 2. is a problem because I'm not sure how I should operate with norms including matrices.

But maybe I could write it like this

$$\|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\|=\left\|\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{A}^{\top} \mathbf{A}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{\top} \mathbf{b}\right\| = 
\left\| A((A^T)^{-1} A^{-1})A^Tb    \right\|$$

mmh bad Idea, this do not help.

I hope you can help me with those maybe trivial questions :)

Comment: Note that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}\neq A^{-1}B^{-1}$ and that in general, since $m$ may be different from $n$, the matrix $A^{-1}$ is not necessarily well defined

Comment: Also, when you say that two norms cannot be equal because one is the norm of a matrix and one of a number, do note that a norm is always a real number, so two norms (of different type of elements) might always be equal.

Comment: @GabrieleCassese  Yes, I noticed that at the end:) But what could I do now? I can not find a counterexample

Comment: @Milloupe Yes, that is true. But actually I found a counterexample for this statement. $ A= \left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{matrix}\right) $ and $ x= \left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\end{matrix}\right) $

Comment: To clarify: I'm not saying that the norm of a 3x2 matrix and of a 2x1 vector will necessarily be equal, just that the way you prove that statement 3 is wrong does not work.